# Conditional Tag Custom Querys?

Tags: query, conditional-tags

I think thats what its called...

Basically a conditional statement if there are any posts in a specific custom post type/custom taxonomy, show posts, it not show an img or include whatever…?

But cycle through a few custom post types?

Checking in each if there is a post in the featured custom tax and if not skip on to the next one, ending up if a temp image or something...

So a conditional tag with query i suppose…

```
if
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'profile','profile-type' => 'featured','posts_per_page' => '-1' ) ); ?>
show post details

else if
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'films','film-type' => 'featured','posts_per_page' => '-1' ) ); ?>
show post details

etc etc

else
show include or temp image
```

Can it be done, or asking a bit too much of the technology?

Many thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `have_posts` function. For more information, visit [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

```
<?php
$loop1 = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'profile',
    'profile-type' => 'featured',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1' ) );
$loop2 = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'films',
    'film-type' => 'featured',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1' ) );

if($loop1->have_posts()) {
    while($loop1->have_posts()) {
        $loop1->the_post();
        // content here
    }
} elseif($loop2->have_posts()) {
    while($loop1->have_posts()) {
        $loop1->the_post();
        // content here
    }
} else {
    // content if all else fails
}
?>
```

Comment: Interesting, i'll give that ago and see how i get on, thanks :)

Comment: I've put that in my template but it results in the page not loading at all.

I need 3 loops though and where it says content here, i need to add an include...

    get_template_part( 'includes/enter' );

Is that possible?

Comment: @Jezthomp - Sorry for the error. I miswrote the code and left out two end parenthesis. I have updated the code above. and `get_template_part` should work like any other code.